# Modeling a greatest integer function

Tags: mathematical-modeling, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to model a function that resembles a greatest integer function. The domain is from [0, $\infty$). The inputs from 0 to 1.5 (non-inclusive) need to be mapped to an output of 0, and 1.5 to $\infty$ mapped to 1. But, I'm trying to not use a piecewise function. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Here's what I've tried:

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor \frac{x}{1.5} \right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this function,

$$\frac{|x-1.5|}{2x-3}+\frac12$$

Although this is very artificial, it works.

Comment: Undefined at $x=1.5$ though.

Comment: And, to satisfy that niggling "no piecewise" concern, consider using $$\frac{\sqrt{(x-1.5)^2}}{2x-3}+\frac12$$ where (obviously) only the positive branch of the square root is used...

Comment: @abiessu Indeed. But the OP mentions trying $\lfloor x/1.5 \rfloor$. So I guess by "piecewise" he meant making his own definition by cases. Otherwise we could just say,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\lt1.5\\1&x\ge1.5\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you state it in a more general form, also?

Comment: @DantheMan In general, $$\frac{|x-n|}{2x-2n}+\frac12$$ where $n$ is the value where you want the "jump"

Answer (score 0):

Your input mapping is currently ambiguous: do you mean to send 1.5 to 0, or 1?

Using a characteristic function:
$$1-\chi_{[0,1.5)}$$
where $\chi_A(x)$ takes the the value $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: 1.5 to 1, sorry.